# Highcharts title text with two dynamic dates

Tags: jsp, dynamic, highcharts, title

In my JSP page I have integrated the highcharts graphs.

The following code fetches 2 different dates from the previous page:

```
String T1=request.getParameter("T1");
String T2=request.getParameter("T2");
```

I want to pass these 2 dates effectively into the title text of the highcharts graph. Please help me in getting the code work.

Below is the code of title text in highcharts:

```
title: {
                text: 'Database Status From ${T1} to ${T2}',
                    style: {fontSize: '10px'}
            },
```

Comment: Is this JSP?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes it is JSP and the  ${T1} ,${T2} is put by me and when I do so, it throws error. please help.

Comment: it's been a while since I've used jsp, but I'll try. What error are you getting? If you look at the code in the developer tools, what do you see for the text string (by then it should be replaced with the values)?

Comment: I am not getting the error as such but my intent was not fulfilled.

Comment: The JavaScript code is as follows:

Comment: var valdt1 = '<%=request.getParameter("T1") %>';
var valdt2 = '<%=request.getParameter("T2") %>';

       chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'PIE',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Database Status From {valdt1}To {valdt2}',
                    style: {fontSize: '10px'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/96AhK/

```
$(function () {
    var valdt1 = 'T1'; //<%=request.getParameter("T1") %>
    var valdt2 = 'T2';  //<%=request.getParameter("T2") %>
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
        { chart: { renderTo: 'PIE', 
                  plotBackgroundColor: null, 
                  plotBorderWidth: null, 
                  plotShadow: false,
                  type: 'pie'}, 
         title: { 
             text: 'Database Status From ' + valdt1 +' To ' + valdt2, 
             style: {fontSize: '10px'}
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

I had to replace out the server side code (request.getParameter) for it to work in jsfiddle, but your code looks right to me.  When you use the variables,build up the string by concatenating the pieces together:

```
text: 'Database Status From ' + valdt1 +' To ' + valdt2,
```

Comment: Thanks Barbara... it worked. Sometimes simple things never strikes the mind. Thats great... Thanks again.
I just replaced/ un-commented the code to:
var valdt1 = <%=request.getParameter("T1") %>
var valdt2 = <%=request.getParameter("T2") %>

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code that worked fine after implementing your(Barbara) suggestion:

```
<script>

$(function () {
    var chart;

var val1 = '<%=instdbout %>';
var val2 = '<%=seconds %>';

var result1 = (val1 / val2) * 100;
var result2 = 100 - result1;

var valdt1 = '<%=request.getParameter("T1") %>';
var valdt2 = '<%=request.getParameter("T2") %>';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Radialize the colors
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });

        // Build the chart 1
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'PIE',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: { 
             text: 'Database Status From ' + valdt1 +' To ' + valdt2, 
             style: {fontSize: '10px'}
         },
```